# How to get month & year from NSDate?

Tags: iphone

Is there any way/ method to seperate month & year form NSDate?

I just need to display current month & year?
Any Example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done by using [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

Comment: NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

Comment: NSDateComponents *currentDateComponents = [gregorian components:( NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit) fromDate:current_date];

Comment: NSLog(@"- current components year = %i , month = %i , week = % i, weekday = %i", [currentDateComponents year], [currentDateComponents month], [currentDateComponents week], [currentDateComponents weekday]);

Answer (score 6):

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date];
NSInteger year = [dateComponents year];
NSInteger month = [dateComponents month];
[calendar release];
```

cheers endo

Comment: what is the `calendar` variable?

Comment: NSCalendar * calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];